# azure web Code only works after a publish

Tags: azure

I am seeing some very strange behavior on my Azure site. When I publish from VS the web site opens and the code works. But when I just paste the URL in the browser the code doesn't work. The specific code is the code that calls my Azure ML API. I am baffled by this one. Anyone have any thoughts on why this would behave this way. BTW. I have the azure SDK installed but my server explorer does not show my web site so I can't debug. I am not using a custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

Clear you browser cache & cookies.

To connect to azure using server explorer. Follow these steps:

**Step 1:**

**[image: Step1 :]**

**Step 2:**

[image]